# Ctrl+a not working for input element in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am using SharePoint dialog UI to populate some items. I have input field on the pop up.
I am trying to select all the text using ctrl+a when input element has focus. Thus I found out the default event is not getting triggered.

Hence, I am using jquery to select as below:

```
$('input').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
        e.target.select();
    }
})
```

However, the above code is working for chrome, but not for IE.
What am I missing here to make it IE compatible? Is it the problem with SharePoint UI?

Comment: Why do you need to use Javascript to achieve this, given that you get the behaviour for free in Windows? Also, anyone on a Mac would use CMD + A to select all the text so if you're trying to override the behaviour you'd need to consider that too.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason, it is not working for me. Therefore I am using jquery to do so.

Comment: Which one is not working ? the if-statement or the keydown function ?

Comment: The whole function. It is working well with chromium.